# pyjamas - pyjsbuild error due to DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyjamas

I am trying to build the HelloWorld example page from the Pyjamas example folder. However I am receiving this error when I run: `sudo pyjsbuild helloworld.py`. This error seems pretty universal to python as it seems to be related to the setup/configuration of my python environment. Any advice on where to look for the problem?

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyjsbuild", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",     line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",     line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py",     line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying the various answers, it turns out `pip` was not properly installing the `six` package, whatever that is. So I ran `sudo easy_install pip (--upgrade)` to make sure the script configuration was right. It wrote some extra files so I assume that's why my next command `sudo pip install six` or `sudo pip install six --upgrade` worked. Now I ran into another error -_-, For anyone looking later: `Runtime Error: Top module not found 'hello world'`

Edit: The top module error is coming from trying to build into the output folder that is not `pyjs/`. All I had to do was move the folder up to `pyjs/` folder in `sitepackages/`.